# How to get elapsed time & format it?

Tags: delphi

I have two unix timestamps as LONG INT. I want to subtract start from end to get elapsed time and format it to hh:mm:ss

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the [`UnixToDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils.UnixToDateTime) and the [`FormatDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FormatDateTime) functions see this sample

```
uses
  DateUtils,
  SysUtils;

var
  StartUnixTime : Int64;
  EndUnixTime   : Int64;

  StartDateTime : TDateTime;
  EndDateTime   : TDateTime;
begin
  try
    StartUnixTime:=1293062827;
    EndUnixTime  :=1293070000;

    //option 1 converting both unix times to TDatetime and then subtract
    StartDateTime:=UnixToDateTime(StartUnixTime);
    EndDateTime  :=UnixToDateTime(EndUnixTime);    
    Writeln(Format('Elapsed time %s',[FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss',EndDateTime-StartDateTime)]));

    //option 2 subtract directly and then convert to TDatetime
    Writeln(Format('Elapsed time %s',[FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss',UnixToDateTime(EndUnixTime-StartUnixTime))]));

  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Additionally if you wanna get the Years, Months and Days , you can use the [`YearsBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils.YearsBetween), [`MonthsBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils.MonthsBetween) and the [`DaysBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils.DaysBetween) functions in this way.

```
Writeln(Format('Years %d Months %d Days %d',[YearsBetween(EndDateTime,StartDateTime),MonthsBetween(EndDateTime,StartDateTime),DaysBetween(EndDateTime,StartDateTime)]));
```

Comment: Don't display the `zzz` section if the input is a Unix time; it only measures seconds, so including milliseconds is introducing precision that you don't really have. Also, beware if the elapsed time is more than 24 hours.

Comment: Rob, you are right, i updated the answer to omit the milliseconds and added the part to show Year, Month and Days.

Answer (score 1):

```
UnixTime1 := 123456;
UnixTime2 := 123460;

Diff := UnixTime2 - UnixTime1;
if Diff > 24 * 60 * 60 then
  raise Exception.CreateFmt('Time difference (%s seconds) is longer than a day.', [Diff]);
s := Format('%.2d:.%2d:%.2d', [Diff div 60 div 60, (Diff div 60) mod 60, Diff mod 60]);
```

Comment: There's no reason for a duration longer than a day to be an exceptional circumstance. It's not like it's any harder to handle than the code that's already here. But if you must throw an exception, be sure to use the right format string for displaying an int, `%d`. Also, dividing using the `/` operator will give floats, not ints. Use `div` instead.

Comment: @Rob: re: >1 day: My first version also added the days as an additional number in front of the hours, but the OP wanted hh:mm:ss format, so I changed it to throw an exception instead. re: / You are right, I should have used div. But hey, that was on Christmas day and I had eaten too much ;-)

Comment: Or you could just let the number of hours exceed 24.

Comment: @Rob: No, in that case it could get > 99 and exceed 2 digits, so no longer fit "hh". Of course that might or might not be an error.

Answer (score 1):

This answer did not produce the results I was looking for.  I opted to use the OvcDate.DateDiff procedure to give the results I was looking for.

```
procedure TBCSJEmpdm.q1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  das, mos, yrs : Integer;
begin
  OvcDate.DateDiff(DateTimeToStDate(DataSet.FieldByName('fromd').AsDateTime),
    DateTimeToStDate(DataSet.FieldByName('tod').AsDateTime), das, mos, yrs);      
  DataSet.FieldByName('das').AsInteger := das;
  DataSet.FieldByName('mos').AsInteger := mos;
  DataSet.FieldByName('yrs').AsInteger := yrs;
end;
```

This approach give the elapsed years, months, and days between two dates.  OvcDate requires ovc.inc file.  Just let me know if you need these.

Comment: Yes, please, @ArchBrooks. Thanks for offering another possibility which can help others in the future (+1).

Comment: Hello folks,

The source code for the OvcDate and ovc.inc are embedded in the link below.  

[OvcDate,pas and Ovc.Inc](http://bcsjava.com/blg/wordpress/2015/02/20/bcs-calculating-elapsed-time-delphi/)

Click on the control that copies to clipboard then paste to the file of your liking.  The ovc,inc file should be keep its name because OvcDate includes "ovc.Inc".

Enjoy!