# Elapsed/time interval in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, date, time, vcl

I need to calculate the elapsed time (nicely formatted) between **now** and a **file's last modification date/time**, [ie. something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515544/how-to-get-elapsed-time-format-it), only in my case, the difference can be in days, months or even years.

I tried this:

```
var
   TimeDiff : Double;
begin
     TimeDiff := Now - FileAgeEx('C:\my-file.txt');
     if (TimeDiff >= 1) then
        Caption  := FormatDateTime('dd hh:nn:ss', TimeDiff)
     else
         Caption := FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', TimeDiff);
end;
```

But (1) it doesn't work and (2) I'd like a better formatting.

Ultimately my goal is to have something like this:

- Time Diff < 1 day   ==> display this:  **12:00:01**
- Time Diff >= 1 day  ==> display this:  **25 days, 12:00:01**
- Time Diff >= 1 year ==> display this:  **2 years, 3 months, 10 days, 12:00:01**

Anyone knows how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main problem would appear to be getting hold of the last modified time of the file. I use the following code:

```
function LastWriteTime(const FileName: string): TFileTime;
var
  AttributeData: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
  if not GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @AttributeData) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Result := AttributeData.ftLastWriteTime;
end;

function UTCFileTimeToSystemTime(const FileTime: TFileTime): TSystemTime;
//returns equivalent time in current locality, taking account of daylight saving
var
  LocalFileTime: Windows.TFileTime;
begin
  Windows.FileTimeToLocalFileTime(FileTime, LocalFileTime);
  Windows.FileTimeToSystemTime(LocalFileTime, Result);
end;

function UTCFileTimeToDateTime(const FileTime: TFileTime): TDateTime;
begin
  Result := SystemTimeToDateTime(UTCFileTimeToSystemTime(FileTime));
end;
```

You call `LastWriteTime` to get the last modified time in file time format. Then call `UTCFileTimeToDateTime` to convert into `TDateTime` accounting for the prevailing local time zone of the machine. You can then compare that value with `Now`.

As regards the formatting, you already appear to know how to do that. You basic approach will work and you just need to flesh out the details.

---

In the comments you say that

```
FormatDateTime('dd hh:nn:ss', 2.9);
```

shows a `1` for the day when you would expect a `2`. The problem is that this function formats dates rather than time intervals. The value `2.9` is not treated as an elapsed time, rather it is treated as an absolute date/time, `2.9` days after the Delphi epoch.  I would use `Trunc` and `Frac` to obtain number of days, and the part of days respectively, and work from there.

```
Days := Trunc(TimeDiff);
Time := Frac(TimeDiff);
```

The following code, extracted directly from my codebase, may give you some pointers. Note that its input is in seconds, but it should set you on the right path.

```
function CorrectPlural(const s: string; Count: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(Count) + ' ' + s;
  if Count<>1 then begin
    Result := Result + 's';
  end;
end;

function HumanReadableTime(Time: Double): string;
//Time is in seconds
const
  SecondsPerMinute = 60;
  SecondsPerHour = 60*SecondsPerMinute;
  SecondsPerDay = 24*SecondsPerHour;
  SecondsPerWeek = 7*SecondsPerDay;
  SecondsPerYear = 365*SecondsPerDay;

var
  Years, Weeks, Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds: Int64;

begin
  Try
    Years := Trunc(Time/SecondsPerYear);
    Time := Time - Years*SecondsPerYear;
    Weeks := Trunc(Time/SecondsPerWeek);
    Time := Time - Weeks*SecondsPerWeek;
    Days := Trunc(Time/SecondsPerDay);
    Time := Time - Days*SecondsPerDay;
    Hours := Trunc(Time/SecondsPerHour);
    Time := Time - Hours*SecondsPerHour;
    Minutes := Trunc(Time/SecondsPerMinute);
    Time := Time - Minutes*SecondsPerMinute;
    Seconds := Trunc(Time);

    if Years>5000 then begin
      Result := IntToStr(Round(Years/1000))+' millennia';
    end else if Years>500 then begin
      Result := IntToStr(Round(Years/100))+' centuries';
    end else if Years>0 then begin
      Result := CorrectPlural('year', Years) + ' ' + CorrectPlural('week', Weeks);
    end else if Weeks>0 then begin
      Result := CorrectPlural('week', Weeks) + ' ' + CorrectPlural('day', Days);
    end else if Days>0 then begin
      Result := CorrectPlural('day', Days) + ' ' + CorrectPlural('hour', Hours);
    end else if Hours>0 then begin
      Result := CorrectPlural('hour', Hours) + ' ' + CorrectPlural('minute', Minutes);
    end else if Minutes>0 then begin
      Result := CorrectPlural('minute', Minutes);
    end else begin
      Result := CorrectPlural('second', Seconds);
    end;
  Except
    Result := 'an eternity';
  End;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! But still something is wrong...`FormatDateTime('dd hh:nn:ss', TimeDiff);` where TimeDiff = `2.9487917361` (almost 3 days between file last modif & now) gives me `01 22:46:15`